# How to compress and resize image from a Rich Text

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor, richtext

I am inserting image in using this

```
var readFileIntoDataUrl = function (fileInfo) {
    var loader = $.Deferred(),
        fReader = new FileReader();
    fReader.onload = function (e) {
        loader.resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    fReader.onerror = loader.reject;
    fReader.onprogress = loader.notify;
    fReader.readAsDataURL(fileInfo);
    return loader.promise();
};


$.when(readFileIntoDataUrl(fileInfo)).done(function (dataUrl) {
        execCommand('insertimage', dataUrl);
}).fail(function (e) {
        options.fileUploadError("file-reader", e);
});
```

Let say i added a text `Hello World` and added a image. Now when i take `$("#editor").html()` it shows something like below

Here is a sample source of a image+text

```
Hello World!
img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBoRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA
BAEaAAUAAAABAAAAPgEbAAUAAAABAAAARgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAARAAAATgAAAAAAAABgAAAA
AQAAAGAAAAABUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuOAAA/9sAQwAHBQUGBQQHBgUGCAcHCAoRCwoJCQoVDxAMERgV
[... more base64 data here....]
```

Now here i have both `text+image` So both on server side and client side i want to resize & compress image

So that no one can insert image > 5MP and also keep a rich text with resize image in my db

Comment: How is Java relevant here? (I'd also suggest that just a line or two of the base64 data is more than enough to give us an indication of what you've got...)

Comment: On server side i get this `text+image` so how will i deal with image compression on server side using java?

Comment: Well your question asks about how you can do it on the client side *and* the server side... it's very unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question pls hv a look

Comment: It's still far from clear to me. Maybe it'll be clear to someone else though...

Comment: Ok let me explain you, You have a page where you write your post. Inside Rich Text Editor your enter some text, and image. When you click submit buttons the html equivalent code of your post is sent to to server, the data that is going to server contains is in the form of `Hello World!
img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/94AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD`. Now on server side I have detect that all image is below 5MB and also resize them so that overall content size will decrease.

Comment: So you *don't* want to try to reduce it on the client side? If that's the case, then all the Javascript is a red herring...

Comment: Client side compression is needed but i don't think I should rely blidly on client side work. I want to send a resized image from client side and on server side i want to recheck if everything is all right if not then i want to resize on server side

Comment: Okay, so I would suggest splitting this into two entirely separate questions. After all, you're talking about very separate bits of code. Both the questions and the answers will be simpler if you handle each side separately.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it on the server side (Java):

```
    String imageData = "Hello World! img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBoR...";

    //Image data starting point
    int startIndex = imageData.indexOf(";base64,") + ";base64,".length();

    //keep only the image data
    imageData = imageData.substring(startIndex, imageData.length());

    //convert the image data String to a byte[]
    byte[] dta = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageData);
    try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(dta);) {
        BufferedImage fullSize = ImageIO.read(in);

        // Create a new image half the size of the original image
        BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(fullSize.getWidth() / 2, fullSize.getHeight() / 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) resized.getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(fullSize, 0, 0, resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), 0, 0, fullSize.getWidth(), fullSize.getHeight(), null);
        g2.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As for the JavaScript part you can use a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), size the canvas to the dimension that you want, draw your image on it and use the [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL) method to convert the image to a `String`